# Encountering selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException only on specific web page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to create a content scraper to gather a list of medical terms and I'm using https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/medical for that task. All I have in my code right now is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/medical/a")
driver.close()
```

The following error message is shown after every run of the program using this or any https://www.merriam-webster.com URL:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mw-download.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get("https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/medical/a")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=https%3A//nop.xpanama.net/if.html%3Fadflag%3D1%26cb%3DKHg6C73w9F&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20nop.xpanama.net.
```

I have tried changing the URL to different sites, with and without https support to test if it was something with https, but I haven't encountered this error with any other site. I also tried removing the `driver.close()` command at the end of the script to see if trying to close the driver before the page contents were loaded is what was causing the problem but the problem persists even without that line of code.

Any help in understanding this error and fixing it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried running your code, and it brings me to the Merrian-Webster site's medical dictionary, with the 'a' words. Is there any other code that might be affecting the posted code? Also, are you using current versions of selenium and webdriver (~3.4)?

Comment: There's no other code that is affecting it. All I have in my program so far is what is posted above. I am running selenium 3.4.3.

Comment: It may be issue with gecko driver as when i execute it on chrome. It is working fine. you can try with chrome as you are scrapping.

Comment: Using it on Chrome works just fine, thanks! I'll be using that from now on. I would still like to understand why it is not working with geckodriver, though, so I will be keeping the question open with hopes that it gets answered at a later date.